# How to load the content of <h> element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a tag like:

```
<h3>Mobile
    <img align="middle" alt="Edit" class="attEditCategory" src="/Images/edit.png">
    <img align="middle" alt="Delete" class="attDeleteCategory" src="/Images/delete.png">
</h3>
```

I want to display the text of h3 ie "Mobile" in edit click button (on alert).

```
$(".attEditCategory").button().on("click", function (event) {});
```

Please help.

Comment: what is `.button()`??

Comment: @Ravi I think he is using [`jquery UI`](http://jqueryui.com/button/)

Comment: @Ravi: Almost certainly a [jQuery UI button](http://jqueryui.com/button/).

Comment: no need for that...just added that for UI. same problem with using $( ".attEditCategory" ).click(function() as well

Comment: @A1rPun --T.J. Crowder yes. its that only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$(this).parent().text()` to get the text. Or `$(this).closest('h3').text()` if there could be more to the hierarchy than shown.

E.g.:

```js
$(".attEditCategory").button().on("click", function (event) {
  alert($(this).parent().text());
});
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<h3>Mobile
    <img align="middle" alt="Edit" class="attEditCategory" src="/Images/edit.png">
    <img align="middle" alt="Delete" class="attDeleteCategory" src="/Images/delete.png">
</h3>
```

If there could be text inside the buttons (e.g., `button` or `a` elements rather than `img`), `$(this).parent().text()` would include that text. So in that hypothetical case, it's more difficult (but still quite simple) to get just the text of the element itself and not the text of its children:

```
alert($(this).parent().contents().map(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3 ? this.nodeValue : ""; // 3 = text node
}).get().join(""));
```

```js
$(".attEditCategory").button().on("click", function (event) {
  alert($(this).parent().contents().map(function() {
      return this.nodeType === 3 ? this.nodeValue : ""; // 3 = text node
  }).get().join(""));
});
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<h3>Mobile
    <a align="middle" alt="Edit" class="attEditCategory">edit</a>
    <a align="middle" alt="Delete" class="attDeleteCategory">delete</a>
</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(".attEditCategory").on("click", function (event) {
    alert($(this).parent().text())

});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Bala_chandran/9y5s4um5/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

SInce the class is a child of the `h3` use `parent()` to target the `<h3>` and `text()` to get the text

```
$(".attEditCategory").button().on("click", function (event) {
   alert( $(this).parent().text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $("h3").text();
```

[Official documentation](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

To access a specific `h3` tag with a class or an id you do something like:

```
 $("#foo").text(); //foo is the id
 $(".foo").text(); //foo is the class
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

`$('h3').text();`

And it returns just: `"Mobile"`. It'll be enough to alert:

```
alert($('h3').text());
```